# Insert results from query into the same table

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, wordpress, insert

(For WordPress folks: I am creating a set of new "custom field"s called sidebar_buy_now by combining pairs of existing "custom field"s.)

I have a table: `wp_postmeta` with 4 fields: `meta_id`,`post_id`,`meta_key`,`meta_value`.

`meta_id`is the primary key and should auto-increment.

I have a working SELECT query which produces the desired result for the last 3 fields: `post_id`,`meta_key`,`meta_value`:

```
SELECT L.`post_id`, "sidebar_buy_now" AS "meta_key",
CONCAT(L.`meta_value`, ' | ',R.`meta_value`) 
AS "meta_value" FROM `wp_postmeta` L INNER JOIN `wp_postmeta` R
ON L.`post_id` = R.`post_id`
AND L.`meta_key` = 'sidebar_buy_now_url' 
WHERE R.`meta_key` = 'sidebar_buy_now_title'
```

I want to insert the results of this query into the `wp_postmeta` table while auto-incrementing `meta_id`.

This is the INSERT query I am trying which does not work:

```
INSERT into `wp_postmeta` (`post_id`,`meta_key`,`meta_value`) 
SELECT L.`post_id`, "sidebar_buy_now" AS "meta_key", 
CONCAT(L.`meta_value`, ' | ',R.`meta_value`) AS "meta_value" FROM `wp_postmeta` L INNER JOIN `wp_postmeta` R ON L.`post_id` = R.`post_id`
AND L.`meta_key` = 'sidebar_buy_now_url' WHERE R.`meta_key` = sidebar_buy_now_title'
```

Getting this error:

`#1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1`.

Perhaps because I don't know how to specify an auto-incrementing meta-id in the SELECT... (?)
Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: `meta_id` column of your table is set to auto_increament??

Comment: If meta_id column is auto-increment then remove that column from Insert into

Comment: Thanks Kannan ! So simple :P  I also had a couple of fields out of order. Corrected that above - works great!

Comment: Why do you insist on that terrible formatting of your question. It's absolutely awful and incorrect use of SO editing tools.

Comment: scsimon - Better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT into wp_postmeta (post_id,meta_key,meta_value)
SELECT
   L.post_id
   ,"sidebar_buy_now" AS "meta_key"
   ,CONCAT(L.meta_value, ' | ',R.meta_value) AS "meta_value"
FROM
   wp_postmeta L
   INNER JOIN wp_postmeta R
   ON L.post_id = R.post_id AND L.meta_key = 'sidebar_buy_now_url'
WHERE R.meta_key = 'sidebar_buy_now_title'
```

Because meta_id is an auto increment column you don't actually insert anything into you.  You simply omit it from the insert statement.

Comment: Matt - correct!  Also - note the change I made in my SELECT statement. I should have had L.post_id before "sidebar_buy_now" AS "meta_key".

Comment: I see that now, I edited answer to reflect that.  Please accept my answer if it worked for you so that others know you have solved your issue and reputation points are awarded here is a link for more about how/when/why if you need it. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work